# The Spotify Web API returns null items for user playlist even when the user has got some playlists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

I used React for this and here is my App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import './App.css';
import { useDataLayerValue } from "./DataLayer";
import { getTokenFromResponse } from "./spotify";

import Login from "./Login";
import Player from "./Player";

import SpotifyWebApi from "spotify-web-api-js";

const spotify = new SpotifyWebApi();

function App() {
  const [{ token }, dispatch] = useDataLayerValue();

  useEffect(() => {
    const hash = getTokenFromResponse();
    window.location.hash = "";
    let _token = hash.access_token;

    console.log(_token)
    if (_token) {
      spotify.setAccessToken(_token);
      dispatch({
        type: "SET_TOKEN",
        token: _token,
      });

      spotify.getMe().then((user) => {
        console.log(user)
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: user,
        });
      });

      spotify.getUserPlaylists().then((playlists) => {
        console.log(playlists)
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_PLAYLISTS",
          playlists: playlists,
        })
      })
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="app">
      {token ? <Player spotify={spotify} /> : <Login />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My spotify.js file

```
export const authEndPoint = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"

const redirectUrl = "http://localhost:3000/"

const clientID = "My_client_ID"

const scopes = [
    "user-read-currently-playing",
    "user-read-recently-played",
    "user-read-playback-state",
    "user-top-read",
    "user-modify-playback-state",
]

export const getTokenFromResponse = () => {
    return window.location.hash
        .substring(1)
        .split("&")
        .reduce((initial, item) => {
            var parts = item.split("=");
            initial[parts[0]] = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);

            return initial;
        }, {});
};

export const loginUrl = `${authEndPoint}?client_id=${clientID}&redirect_uri=${redirectUrl}&scope=${scopes.join("%20")}&response_type=token&show_dialog=true`
```

When I run the server the response I get is

```
{href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/syq0nm9vazzq9oddoozq2z5d3/playlists?offset=0&limit=20", items: Array(0), limit: 20, next: null, offset: 0, …}
href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/syq0nm9vazzq9oddoozq2z5d3/playlists?offset=0&limit=20"
items: []
limit: 20
next: null
offset: 0
previous: null
total: 0
__proto__: Object
```

This is what is shown in my console but I have got 2 playlists in my spotify account.
I am creating this with the help of a tutorial. I am currently a learner. It worked perfectly fine in the tutorial. IS there bugs in my code??

Someone please help me I have spent 3 days looking for suggestions.

Comment: what do you see in browsers network tab? Also try sending the API through postman or any rest client and see results. This will help you to figure out if the issue is in your react code or API call

Comment: @igk I have tried it but still it returns items: null. 
I have even tried spotify's own web api trial using OAuth token and got the same result

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. The issue for me was that the playlists I had weren't added to my profile. So what I did was: on my playlists in Spotify I clicked on the '...' and then from the options I clicked on "add to profile". After the playlists were added to my profile, I was able to display them in my app.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to go into your `App.js` file, look in the  `spotify.getUserPlaylists(userId)` and add your spotify user ID and I think it will run.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for helping with answering questions. Did you know you can format your code to be easier to read? [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

I've just experienced this problem.You must also include in the authorization scopes array the 'read' ones: [playlist-read-collaborative](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/scopes/#playlist-read-collaborative) and [playlist-read-private](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/scopes/#playlist-read-private), as it is stated in both sections of the docs that the [Get Current User's Playlists](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/get-a-list-of-current-users-playlists) endpoint requires these two authorization scopes. Still, I am not sure that 200 is the right answer/status code coming from the API when the client has no authorization and the answer for this case is either some data or none.

Your 'My spotify.js' file should look something like this:

```
export const authEndPoint = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"

const redirectUrl = "http://localhost:3000/"

const clientID = "My_client_ID"

const scopes = [
    "user-read-currently-playing",
    "user-read-recently-played",
    "user-read-playback-state",
    "user-top-read",
    "user-modify-playback-state",
    "playlist-read-collaborative",
    "playlist-read-private"
]
...
```